# I need to build some word search function in C++, but seems its not work. Any clue?

Tags: c++

Below is the code I write, the `if` statements are to determine weather or not the word is in the sentence, but wants to have a function. Can anyone exam this and what

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string> 
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
char sentence[50]; 
char search [50];
int numtimes = 0;

cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl; 
gets_s (sentence); 
cout << endl; 
cout << "Your sentence is: \n" << sentence << endl;


cout << "Enter a any word: " << endl;
gets_s (search);
cout << endl;
cout << "The word is: " << search << endl;

int i, len;
int j, lenS;
len = strlen(sentence); 
lenS = strlen(search);


for (i = 0; i < len - lenS + 1; i++)
{
    if (sentence[i] == search[0])
    {
        for (j = 0; j < lenS; j++)
        {
            if (sentence[i+j] != search[j])
                break; 
        }
        if (j == lenS)
        {
            cout << "search found\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (i == len - lenS +1)
{
    return 1;
}



system("PAUSE"); 
return 0; }
```

Comment: This is far more C. Judging by your loops, all you need are `std::string`s (which actually input properly) and the `find` member.

Comment: Is there any error that you are getting?

Comment: Why don't you put some `cout` statements inside your loops, to show how far the comparison is getting and whether it matches the conditions you expect etc....?

Comment: with C++11 you get the regex too http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/ . Your code is clearly not that C++-ish, not that portable either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this for studying functions and parameters. I have made minimal changes to your code, just to show how to put the code in a function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// the function is here
bool searchWord(char* sentence, char* search)
{
    int i, len;
    int j, lenS;
    len = strlen(sentence);
    lenS = strlen(search);

    bool found = false;
    for (i = 0; i < len - lenS + 1; i++)
    {
        if (sentence[i] == search[0])
        {
            for (j = 0; j < lenS; j++)
            {
                if (sentence[i+j] != search[j])
                    break;
            }
            if (j == lenS)
            {
                //cout << "search found\n";
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (i == len - lenS +1)
    {
        found = false;
    }

    return found;
}

int main ()
{
    char mySentence[50];
    char mySearch [50];
    int numtimes = 0;

    cout << "Enter a sentence: " << endl;
    gets (mySentence);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Your sentence is: \n" << mySentence << endl;


    cout << "Enter a any word: " << endl;
    gets (mySearch);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The word is: " << mySearch << endl;

    if (searchWord(mySentence, mySearch)) {
        cout << "Found\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not Found\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0; 
  }
```

Two things to note:

1. You might want to check for a space after finding the last letter of the word. Example:
   Sentence: The sentences should be English
   Word: sentence
2. string.h has several functions that can be handy in this type of tasks.